# If $V$ is a $\mathbb{C} G$-module whose character is real then dim$V$ and dim $V^G$ have the same parity.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group of odd order. Prove that if $V$ is a $\mathbb{C} G$-module whose character is real, then dim$V$ and dim$V^G$ have the same parity.

where $V^G:=\{v \in V \mid vg=v \forall g \in G\}$ and having the same parity means they are both odd or both even.

What I have got so far: Since $G$ is of odd order, we can show $g$ is not conjugate to $g^{-1}$ for all $g \in G\setminus \{1\}$. It follows that there is only one irreducible character which is real (i.e. the trivial character).

So if $V$ is an irreducible character, then its character is the trivial character. That is , it is the trivial $\mathbb{C} G$-module, so $V^G=V$ in this case and the result follows.

But if $V$ is reducible, then $1<dim V^G <dim V$. How can I show, in this case that they have the same parity?

Comment: Since $\#G$ is odd, we just need $\sum_{g\neq 1}\chi_V(g)$ to be even.  Can you show that?

Comment: @user10354138  What I know is, if $G$ has $k$ irreducible characters, then $|G|=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \chi_{i}^{2}(1)$ which implies $\sum_{i=2}^{k}\chi_{i}^{2}(1)$ is even

Comment: @user10354138 Is it true that $|G|=\sum_{g \in G} \chi_{V}(g)$?

Comment: @user10354138 Moreover, why is this result useful to prove the statement?

Answer (score 1):

First note that, since $\#G$ is odd, we can invert it mod 2:
$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align*}
\dim V\equiv\dim V^G&\iff\chi_V(1)\equiv\langle\chi_V,1_G\rangle=\frac1{\#G}\sum_{g\in G}\chi_V(g)\\
&\iff\cancelto{1}{\color{red}{\#G}}\cdot\chi_V(1)\equiv\sum_{g\in G}\chi_V(g)\\
&\iff\sum_{g\neq 1}\chi_V(g)\equiv 0
\end{align*}
$$
So it suffices to show
$$s:=\frac12\sum_{g\neq 1}\chi_V(g)$$
is an integer.

Recall $\chi_V(g)$ is an algebraic integer (it is sum of roots of unity), and $\chi_V(g^{-1})=\overline{\chi_V(g)}$.  Since $\chi_V$ is real, $\chi_V(g)=\chi_V(g^{-1})$ so summing one representative from each $\{g,g^{-1}\}$, we get $s$ is an algebraic integer.  On the other hand,
$$s=\frac12[(\#G)\cdot\dim V^G-\dim V]\in\mathbb{Q}.$$
So $s\in\mathbb{Z}$ since $\mathbb{Z}$ is integrally closed.

Comment: great proof. Didn't expect it has something to do with algebraic integers. Thanks a lot!